# Scan target list with ports included

Tags: nmap

Is there a way to scan a list of targets with nmap and put in the list of targets, ports like the following:

```
1.1.1.1:80,443
2.2.2.2:3389,636
3.3.3.3:23,21
```

Or is there an easy way of doing this, i don't want to scan all the ports in the list, i only want to scan the ip and the associated ports to it?

Answer (score 1):

Using files with predefined targets to scan to Nmap is pretty easy, in the file you only need to set a target, or a range per line. Create a file called targets by running:

- open a new file (`nano file_name`) and write your targets in the file:

Example:

```sh
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.10
192.168.0.17
test.com
target.com
...
```

- Now use the target file in nmap with down command:

`nmap -iL file_path`

Comment: yes i agree that part i know, how to add a targets list, but what i want to know if its even possible is to include ports in that last, so i can specify the ip with which ports to scan it, if i only have the list of targets it will scan all ports based on the -p option